# Jenkins pipline with Robotframework UI test cases

Tags: robotframework

Have setup jenkins pipline with my robot framework but my project structure is

```
Parent folder/
│
├── module 1/
│   ├── TC1.robot
│   └── TC2.robot
│
└── module 2/
    ├── TC1.robot
    └── TC2.robot
```

I am running command to execute test cases in below way

```
robot -d results path/to/module1/
```

then all test cases get executed and same for module2 but then I do rebot to merge all test case. 
I would like to get some input on how can I execute all test cases in one go in jenkins and if some test cases fail I should be able to re execute and rebot all test cases and send final report.

I tried to write execute as windows command in jenkins.
Path to all module test cases
rerun failed test cases
rebot

but that script has become long. 
can someone please provide best way to execute?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should declare the output files using `-o`

If you're looking to rerun your failed test you can `-R` or `--rerunfailed` with robot or pabot for parallel execution.

Then run `--merge` with rebot and call the two output folders you require.

This is separated to make it more readable but I have this running on a single line in Jenkins.

```
pabot -d results  -o Output.xml Tests & 
pabot -d results -o rerun.xml -R results\Output.xml Tests & 
rebot -d results --merge results/Output.xml results/rerun.xml
```

In your case Tests would be 'Parent Folder'

Comment: Was this any help to you initial issue?

Comment: Yes, it helped me a lot of. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example I would set the folder to the common parent. All test cases in both folders will then be executed.

```
robot -d results parent folder/
```

Comment: Since `parent folder` has a space in it, you'll need to use quotes on the command line: `robot -d results 'parent folder/'`

Comment: Thank you all. Have provided my run.bat file content please review and do let me know the feedback.  robot -d results  C:\robot\parentfolder\   I assume that once this command gets executed I would have few test case failure then I do  robot --rerunfailed results/rerun_1.xml --output rerun_2.xml  C:\robot\parentfolder\     and finally I am merging all results  rebot --merge results/rerun_1.xml rerun_2_1.xml   I have written all these in run.bat file.

Comment: @A.Kootstra yes, it worked. I have around 300 test cases and few of them get failed. so thought of writing above set of command in run.bat. can you please review if you have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to run:

```
robot -L INFO path/to/module1/
```

Comment: Vikash, I appreciate your reply. but this command will execute all test cases from module 1 and will stop there.